# Angular CLI: 9.0.6: An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/build-angular/package.json'

Tags: angular-cli

Package pulled from Git. It works perfectly fine in my other machine (windows). But when i pulled it in my Mac,and tried to build it.. it shows the following error.

I already tried to npm clear caches --force, etc....

**Angular CLI: 9.0.6
Node: 13.8.0
OS: darwin x64**

````
Require stack:
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node/node-modules-architect-host.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/serve-impl.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/export-ref.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/utilities/json-schema.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command-runner.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/cli/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/init.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:980:15)
    at Function.resolve (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:78:19)
    at WorkspaceNodeModulesArchitectHost.resolveBuilder (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node/node-modules-architect-host.js:41:41)
    at ServeCommand.initialize (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js:134:55)
    at async ServeCommand.validateAndRun (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command.js:124:9)
    at async Object.runCommand (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command-runner.js:201:24)
    at async default_1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/cli/index.js:62:31) ```
````

Comment: Are you running as sudo or normal user?

Comment: I tried to run it using both. it gives me the same errors